# Resource on the Lee-Yang zeroes of the partition function of random $3$-SAT problems

Tags: sat, phase-transition, random-k-sat

Could anyone point me to the representative papers on the study of the Lee-Yang zeroes of the partition function of random $3$-SAT problems?

Comment: random k sat and phase transition: you could start with franco: 
Results related to threshold phenomena research in ...www.sciencedirect.com › science › article › pii › pdf
by J Franco · 2001 · Cited by 53 — John Franco1. ECECS, University of Cincinnati, Cincinnati, OH, 45221-0030, USA. Abstract ... J. Franco/Theoretical Computer Science 265 (2001) 147–157 and then from ... Let Fk(n; m) denote a random k-SAT formula of m clauses taken.